# Adding new items to the beginning of listview, and maintaining the scroll position

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem, listview-adapter

I have the following scenario for which I can't find a solution.
I have a listView of items, now, when the user scrolls up the listView i want to load more and more items at the beginning of the listView, in such a way that the user will never get to the head(top) of the listView, and just continue scrolling.

The problem is that after I'm adding items to the list, I'm getting a little gap\jump in the listView - all the items are moving a little bit up and not staying where they are **on the scream** as it should be.

Example:

The listView indexes are:

0

1

2

3

4  <- first visible item

5

6

7

8  <- last visible item

9

10

now, lets say that the user scrolled up and got to item 3, in such scenario I'm adding 
item at the be of the listView:

example:

0-7 are new items

0

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8   <- the "3" item from before
9

10

11

12

13

14

15

I don't won't the user be aware that the listView got bigger, so I'm trying to manipulate the positions and offsets of the listView in such a way that the current showen listViews items doesn't move.

```
int position = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
listView.setSelectionFromTop(position + NUM_OF_NEW_ITEMS, 0);
```

that's way I'm getting to the BEGINNING of the top most view that is display, but if the view wasn't interlay showen on the screen - I'm getting a jump in the size of the offset of that item(the distance between the beginning of that item and the beginning of the listView appearance on the screen)

does anyone have a clue how to solve it? maybe to play with the scroller position or adding the offset size to the listview current position somehow?

I hope that I was clear
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're looking for a dynamically loading listview, with particular loading preferences, there are several libs for this like `EndlessAdapter`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

or if you just want some code you can doctor up yourself: http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-never-ending-list/

Comment: The links in this answer are broken.